# If is_page include/else not working all of a sudden

Tags: php

I've had the same code on my wordpress site for more than a year, and it's stopped working. This is part of page.php:

```
<?php
if (is_page( 83571 )) { 
  include('adsense-schools.php');
} else { 
  include('adsense.php');
}
?>
```

Previously, this used to work, but today I noticed that it is not working correctly. adsense.php is included on all other pages, but adsense-schools.php does not show on page 83571. (And I have checked to make that sure that page id didn't change, the URL when editing that page ends in ...wp-admin/post.php?post=83571)

I also tried changing to page title instead of page id number, so

```
<?php
if (is_page( 'international-schools' )) { 
  include('adsense-schools.php');
} else { 
  include('adsense.php');
}
?>
```

But that didn't work either. Am I missing anything?

Comment: `is_page()` is for front-end use, not use in the admin panel. Might be easier to just check against `$_GET['post']`

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that this is in page.php

Comment: And you're certain that `83571` is a post type = page and not a post or some other post type?

Comment: Yes. When I go to edit at the top it says "Edit Page" and not "Edit Post."

Comment: have you checked that adsense-schools.php still exists and is unchanged?

Comment: Yes, I checked. It has been the same since last year. It's the same as the one for adsense.php but with different numbers for the widget. (<?php echo do_shortcode('[do_widget id=enhancedtextwidget-50]'); ?></div>)

I tried just replacing it with text to see if the widget was the issue, but the text does not appear, either.

Comment: Got it figured out -- a few months ago the page template was changed for this specific page and the new template did not include the conditional to check if it was the schools page. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works you can alternatively try the following:

```
global $post;

<?php if( $post->ID == 83571) { ?>

      include('adsense-schools.php');

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Will this work if the page is a page and not a post?

Comment: Yes it should. If you need to double check echo $post->ID.